# Disable Scroll on a UIWebView allowed?

Tags: ios, scroll, uiwebview

I have to show a web article with a `UITableView` under the article.

The only option I found was to display the article in a `UIWebView` in the tableView header.

In order to do that I have to get the height of the webView content and I have to disable scrolling for the webView.

I found two solutions to disable scrolling:

```
for (id subview in webView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).scrollEnabled=NO;
```

or in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
touchMove = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I heard that the first solution is forbidden by Apple but I don't have any proof of it.
Will my application be rejected by using this solution? If so, can I use the second solution without being rejected?

Answer (score 302):

Starting with iOS5 we have direct access to the scrollview of the UIWebView. 
You can disable scrolling and bounces like this:

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; 
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Comment: For some reason, this is not working for me. :-( I have put a ScrollView and have put a UIWebView in it. Then set the above 2 lines in viewWillAppear method. But the scroll still works in web view. Can someone help?? Just for information, I'm running it in iOS 7 simulator.

Comment: what's the use of `webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;`? since the code in the first line has disabled the scrolling.

Comment: Love it when people take an answer and run without taking the time to give the contributor an up vote. Is there no way to notify the user to please choose an answer to vote ?

Comment: for swift webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false  /
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false

Comment: only `webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; ` worked for me, no need to implement `webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;`

Comment: Swift 4 version: webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

Answer (score 26):

Since this question is still applicable, there is a new way to do it! (iOS 7.0+, perhaps iOS 6 also, not confirmed)

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Take care :)

Comment: What I don't understand is why that isn't in IB :/, cmon APPLE what're you doing! Very nice solution nonetheless!

Answer (score 20):

You can simply set the web view user interaction property to no i.e.

```
webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Its pretty simple and works fine,thanks :)

Comment: However, this prevents links from being tapped.

Comment: @GrahamPerks I have edited the answer with respect to your comment,kindly review it and approve,thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

for all ios versions you can use this code instead of setScrollEnabled :

```
for (UIView *view in webview.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
       UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)view;
       scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: firstly, i try "setScrollEnabled" method and apple rejected my ipa. Then i changed this method and accepted.

Answer (score 11):

Use this one `<body ontouchmove="event.preventDefault()">`

Answer (score 11):

SWIFT 3 version

```
    webView.scrollView.bounces = false
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
touchMove = function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
}
```

is far the best solution.

Indeed :

Your first examle, or the

```
[[[WebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollingEnabled:NO];
```

one (same things) could be rejected because not documented, or make you app crash in a further ios update.

And the

```
[[myWebView scrollView] setBounces:NO];
```

method won't work with iOS < 5.

Answer (score 5):

```
[[[WebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollingEnabled:NO];
```

that sorted it for me

Comment: Would be so wrong to rely on this as it is not an exposed API.

Comment: [[[WebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollingEnabled:NO];

that sorted it for me.

Anyway, it doesn't answer my question.

My question is I'm a allowed to do that?
It seems that disabling scroll through the SDK is forbidden.
But I'm not sure.
And what about disabling scroll through javascript.

Comment: there is no evidence that my suggestion would cause a rejection by apple, infact, by calling the last subiew in the subviews array and setting scrollingEnabled against it is exposed API? surely?. and yeah go for it cause you can use it. no idea via javascript though. sorry.

Comment: No, you should not do this.  As Deepak says, you can't rely on the undocumented internal order of subviews in one of Apple's UI elements.  If they change the internal structure in a future OS update, your application will crash.  They specifically warn about doing this in multiple places, and many applications broke in the upgrade to iPhone OS 3.0 just because they did this.

Answer (score 5):

The first is rejected by Apple. It happened to me just this morning.

Answer (score 5):

[[myWebView scrollView] setBounces:NO];

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the first option is forbidden by Apple.

You could try

```
[[[Webview subviews] lastObject] setScrollingEnabled:NO];
```

If you don't want any links to work in your UIWebView, you can also do

```
[myWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use it :

```
[[webView scrollView] setBounces:NO];
[[webView scrollView] setScrollingEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
[(UIScrollView *)[[webView subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 3):

I placed some `UIWebView`s inside a `UIScrollView` and it wasn't scrolling for me, unless I disable the user interaction on the webviews (even with the `[[webview scrollview] setScrollEnabled:NO]`). So I placed the `UIWebView`s inside a `UIView` and that worked for me but then the interactive links or divs in my HTML inside the `UIWebView` were not working anymore.

The only thing that worked for me is to keep the `UIWebView` inside the `UIScrollView` so the HTML interactions work but the `UIScrolling` does not.

I then created a custom delegate for the webviews to listen for `window.open("http:/customEvent")` that is called from the HTML contained in the webview. I also added a JavaScript swipe detection that will fire up my custom event.

When the webview delegate receives this, I pass a notification to a controller which then dynamically scrolls my `UIScrollView`. Obviously I had to build a logic to monitor and scroll to the next or previous page.  Not the prettiest solution but It's working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your HTML (`<HEAD>` tag)

```
<script> 
  document.ontouchmove = function(event) { event.preventDefault(); }
</script>
```

It will disable scrolling on your web page.

(works on any webpage, not just UIWebView)

Answer (score 2):

I needed to disable scrolling because dismissing a custom keyboard really messed up scrolling with the webView. Nothing else worked and I resorted to something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.webView.scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
  self.webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
}  

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset, CGPointZero)){
        self.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is a UIWebview and a UITableView on a UIScrollview, and setting the height of the webview (and adding to the total ContentSize of the Scrollview) like what you want?

Comment: Almost.
 But it seems less complicated to display the WebView in the tableView header.

But my question Is: I'am allowed to disable webView scroll through SDK? If not I am allowed to do taht trough javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[[WebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollingEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: it will work until the update where the scroll view place would change