# Prevent mobile safari from scrolling page when textarea focused

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications

As the title suggests, I need a workaround to prevent mobile safari from scrolling the document when a textarea is focused. The default behavior is to scroll the page so the textarea's top is aligned with the top of the window. I just want my page to stay put. Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437911/disable-scroll-on-a-uiwebview-allowed)

Comment: so, you want the textarea hidden behind the soft keyboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with this

```
// javascript.js
var locked_scroll = false;
var last_pos = 0;

document.getElementById('my-text').addEventListener('focus', function(event){
    console.log('set locked');
    locked_scroll = true;
    last_pos = document.getElementById('wrapper').scrollTop
});

document.getElementById('my-text').addEventListener('blur', function(event){
    console.log('set unlocked');
    locked_scroll = false;
});

document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener("scroll", function(event){

    if(locked_scroll) {
        event.target.scrollTop = last_pos;
    }

}, true);
```

the event scroll only works when the element have a fixed height and the **overflow** property set to *auto* or *scroll*

```
#wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;    
}
```

check the example:  http://jsfiddle.net/4YkNj/

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function blockMove() {
      event.preventDefault() ;
}
</script>
```

and

```
<input name="textbox" type="text" value="" onkeyup="blockMove;"/>
```

Maybe you need a timer to allow the browser to scroll the textarea to top before blocking the movement.

Comment: This would be a valid solution. Although some more thought into how you would need to implement it would be required. On a focus event etc maybe?