# Scrollable <textarea> in iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile, cordova, iscroll4

I use phoneGap 1.1.0 and iScroll 4.1.9 to build a iPhone & android app.
On android- scroll textarea work fine.
But, on iPhone the textarea is not scrolling.
**Two fingers scrolling doesn't work on my iPhone 3GS (iOS 5.0.1)**
Any one has solution?
thanks.

Comment: I would be interested in this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from what I think you're trying to do and disable the "frame" of the app from scrolling offscreen with:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Unfortunately, I've tried every combination I can think of including the new `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` CSS property (to no avail). Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Thanks, It's actually my issue. but i need it to prevent whole page scroll when scrolling over top or bottom of textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but I found a solution:

This answer to this question stops the UIScrollView in UIWebView from scrolling:
[Disable Scroll on a UIWebView allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437911/disable-scroll-on-a-uiwebview-allowed)

I added this code in the viewDidLoad function of MainViewController.m

```
for (UIView *view in webview.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
       UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)view;
       scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Next issue is preventing iScroll from handling events on TextArea, for this you need to get the debug version of iscroll so you can change the code (3rd line):

```
handleEvent: function (e) {
    var that = this;
    if(e.srcElement.tagName == "TEXTAREA") return; // don't handle textarea
    switch(e.type) {
        case START_EV:
            if (!hasTouch && e.button !== 0) return;
            that._start(e);
            break;
        case MOVE_EV: that._move(e); break;
        case END_EV:
        case CANCEL_EV: that._end(e); break;
        case RESIZE_EV: that._resize(); break;
        case WHEEL_EV: that._wheel(e); break;
        case TRNEND_EV: that._transitionEnd(e); break;
    }
}
```

and also don't preventDefault for your textarea using similar if.

This combination worked for me.

The -webkit and overflow css tags just make it look nicer.

Uh, and on ios 4 the scrolling is done by two fingers and not by one.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it in the next chance.