# UIScrollView subviews contents size issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am using a scrollView, in which i have added some static content in a container view and below this container view i have added a web view and added both these views into my scrollView, I dont want the web view to be scroll, instead I want that my scrollview should scroll according to the height of my container view and height of contents in web view.

Note: I am loading contents in webview as html string, that i am receiving from server, The contents are coming in between of html tags and i am then passing this as a string to web view.

Thanks

Comment: post the screen shot...

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```
  CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;

  for (UIView *subview in scrollview.subviews ) {
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect,subview.frame);
  }

  scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollview.bounds.size.width, CGRectGetMaxY(contentRect));
```

Answer (score 0):

set scrollview Content Size as `containerview height + webview height`

and your `webview Height` must be equal to the `content Size of that Webview` because you don't want to scroll your webview.

Answer (score 0):

1. [find height of contents in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13123055/1704346)
2. make it the size of webview,containerview frame and scrollview contentsize
3. [disable scroll of webview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9005690/1704346)